# Symfony2 - Customising the errors on the "default" login form

Tags: php, symfony

I am using the basic login form shown in the Symfony2 Documentation to allow users to authenticate themselves.

However, I find it a bit lacking in terms of styling it.

Because it is created with basic HTML and not the Form Builder, I am unable to use a form theme. The errors generated by failed login attempts are being output in one block, above the form. In order to look like other forms I have built, I wish to put the error messages next to the input boxes that the error relates to.

I started to go about changing the form to a form created with the Form Builder, but I got stuck when it came to the big task of creating a custom authentication class.

So, is there a way to split the errors object and put them next to the relevant inputs, or should I go full ahead with using a fully custom form and a custom authenticator?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use your own form, without having to do an entire different auth provider.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form

Create the controller action, the route to /login pointing to that action and your own templates. Check that the field names are _username and _password so it works off the bat, or simply go and [configure them](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-form-login).

Comment: I know this, and this is what I have (if you read, I used the example from the Symfony2 Documentation). The issue is the way errors are handled. They are totally different to typical form errors.

Comment: As you can see in the sample, the errors are actually passed as an argument to the template and there simply printed in the template. You could simply split them up and change them in whatever fashion you like inside the controller and then hand them over to the form. Best practice is though to not let potential attackers know if they have a correct username but a wrong password. If you wish to do some simple validation, I'd suggest client side javascript.

Comment: You say "simply split them up" - how? The code to handle the errors in the Controller is totally different to anything else I have seen. Can you explain how, based on the code used in the Documentation?

Comment: $error in the sample is a [AuthenticationException](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Exception/AuthenticationException.html). I'd suggest dumping getExtraInformation() for more details. The rest is just in the normal message of the Exception.

Comment: This still doesn't solve my problem. The default login method is simply too disimilar to "normal" forms.

Comment: Then what are the errors you want to put beside the boxes? Maybe the question needs some clarification on that.

Comment: Pretty sure I explained it rather well. Anyway, with the login form shown in the Documentation, the errors generated with SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR are output in one block, above the form (yes, this block can be moved anywhere) but with a typical form, using the Form Builder, classes, validators and form themes, I can put the individual input errors next to the inputs. The problem I face is that my current block of errors cannot be split up.

Comment: I'm sorry I seem not to ask properly. What kind of errors do you expect, that you wish to display besides those boxes? I gave you the way on how to catch all the errors the system might output. If you wish to add specific things, like additional validators (although I don't see why) then you have to make up your own form, and Authentication Handler. I'm currently working on exactly that (for other reasons) and it's not exactly a pretty thing to do. If you can avoid it, do so :)